# click xpath logo alt impossible

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I would like to click the logo of the website `https://www.mister-auto.com/`

my java code is:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*img[contains(@alt, 'Logo Mister-auto')]))")).click();`

however, i don' t know what' s wrong, it doesn' t work

thanks

Comment: `//*img` is invalid XPath. Try either `//img` or `//*`. Also parentheses are redundant - you can remove them

Comment: Hi, something like this ? : driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//img[contains(@alt, 'Logo Mister-auto'])")).click();

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//img[@alt = 'Logo Mister-auto']")).click();`

Comment: works perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

XPATH

```
//img[contains(@src,'logo-mister')]
```

CSS Selector

```
img[src*='logo-mister']
```